# Search song by title and artist on iTunes in iPhone from my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, itunes

I wants to search song by title and artist on iTunes in iPhone from my app

this is what I m trying to search:

```
 NSString *searchString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"itms://itunes.com/search?term=%@+%@",[[_songsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"artist"],[[_songsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]];

 NSString *newString =[searchString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newString]];
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see any question. What doesn't work? What is the expected result and the result you're getting?

Comment: [Search API](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html)

Comment: I want iTunes will be opened from my app and it will show me the list with results for my search string @GuillaumeAlgis

Comment: @Desdenova Search Api give me a xml, but i want to get opened iTunes with my search string

Comment: Read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/iTunesLinks/iTunesLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH3-SW1 It's not as easy as you might think. You need online [iTunes Link Maker](https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/us/)

Comment: @Desdenova How can i use iTunes link maker in my app?